How to disable smooth scrolling in Ubuntu system-wide?
Smooth scrolling is not working well with my mouse, I would like to disable it, so it acts like Firefox when it is disabled, the text scrolls in blocks instead of smoothly.
I cannot find how to do this, I would like all Ubuntu to not use smooth scrolling, including System Settings, the File Manager, Text Editor. I am hoping for a global Wayland or GTK setting. I can only see answers relating to natural scrolling but this is not smooth scrolling.
